# adding class names to arcs from data in d3.layout.pie()

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a pie chart from a JSON file. I wonder if there is a way I can take some names from the JSON file and assign them as class names of the arcs created by d3.layout.pie().

Here is an example I created: http://blockbuilder.org/jinlong25/532d889e01d02cef2d24

Essentially, I want to do something like the last line of code below:

```
var data = [
  {
    'name': 'apple',
    'value': 250
  },
  {
    'name': 'banana',
    'value': 100
  },
  {
    'name': 'orange',
    'value': 150
  }
];

var arcs = svg.selectAll('g.arc')
              .data(pie(data.map(function(d) { return d.value; })))
              .enter().append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(70, 70)')
              .attr('class', function(d) { return d.name; };
```

but since the data has been transformed by pie(), I wonder if there is anyway to add class names to the data generated by pie().

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some D3 layouts mutate the original dataset but others create a new dataset (like voronoi). In those cases, you can use the array position from the original dataset when working with the new dataset. So from your example:

```
var arcs = svg.selectAll('g.arc')
          .data(pie(data.map(function(d) { return d.value; })))
          .enter().append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(70, 70)')
          .attr('class', function(d,i) { return data[i].name; };
```

Answer (score 2):

d3's layouts helpfully provide a [.value() accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#value) which allows you to specify how get the value of the datum, instead of doing the data.map() operation.  So, you could do:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d.value; })
```

That way, your original datum is preserved in d.data.

So using that definition of pie, your code would change to this:

```
var arcs = svg.selectAll('g.arc')
          .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(70, 70)')
          .attr('class', function(d) { return d.data.name; };
```

edit: added link the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This is what I was looking for originally.